# Website layout works perfectly in Chrome/ Safari but not firefox

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome

So i've worked hard on this website and got to the point where its actually done, however its not working properly on firefox then it does on Chrome/ safari etc. On the contact page the text fields overlap the right column. 
The home page doesnt stretch down far enough then in chrome and safari.

What do I do to fix this problem

The website: http://www.growinhealth.org.uk/contact.php

I am still learning HTML/CSS so please go easy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers handle widths of input fields differently, so I would add a class to the input tags and textarea tag that you want to fix the width of like so:

```
    <input class='yourClass'></input>
    <textarea class='yourClass'></textarea>
```

Then fix the width in the CSS

```
    .yourClass{width:300px}
```

As for your homepage, it seems that in Firefox the div you call "content1" is too short, so I would put in the CSS

```
    #content1{height:1400px}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've applied the change on the homepage and it works great :)

But I don't know what i'm doing wrong with the contact page, the class is working great on all browsers but I must be putting the </textarea> tags in the wrong place :(

Comment: Never mind,I just built a new form and it works fine across all browsers